# Only three types of limit of distributions truncated to a finite interval in the upper tail?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, asymptotics

Suppose random variable $X$ has a continuous probability distribution with an unbounded upper tail; that is, the CDF of $X$ (call it $F$) is absolutely continuous and $F(x)<1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}.$

Now consider the conditional CDF of ${X-a\over w}$ given that $a\le X\le a+w$, for $w>0$:$$G(y,a,w):=\mathbb{P}\left({X-a\over w}\le y\ {\LARGE \mid}\ a\le X\le a+w\right) ={F(a+w\,y)-F(a)\over F(a+w)-F(a)}\,1_{0\le y\le 1}+1_{y>1}.$$

[WolframCloud computations](https://develop.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/eb6b8ff9-d283-4177-bfa8-7ce6e2c9ab50) lead to the following ...

> **Observation**: Apparently, for all well-known parametric families of such distributions (e.g., Normal, Lognormal, Student's t, Cauchy, Maxwell, Gamma, Gumbel, Weibull, etc.), **there are only three types of limit of the CDF of ${X-a\over w}\mid a\le X\le a+w$ as $a\to\infty$**:
>   $$\lim_{a\to\infty}G(y,a,w)=\lim_{a\to\infty}\mathbb{P}\left({X-a\over w}\le y\ {\LARGE \mid}\ a\le X\le a+w\right) \\[3ex]
> = \begin{cases} 
> 1_{y>0} & \text{(Type 1: Degenerate at $0$)}\\[2ex]
> y\,1_{0\le y\le 1}+1_{y>1} & \text{(Type 2: Uniform on $[0,1]$)}\\[2ex]
> {1- e^{-y\,w/\beta}\over 1-e^{-w/\beta}}1_{0\le y\le 1}+1_{y>1} & \text{(Type 3: Exponential$(\beta/w)$ on $[0,1]$)}
> \end{cases}$$ 
>   where $\beta$ is a parameter depending on the $X$ distribution.

**NB**: The Type 3 limit depends on both $w$ and the $X$ distribution, but the Type 1 and Type 2 limits are *free of w and free of all parameters of the $X$ distribution*, which seems quite remarkable.

**NB**: Letting $Y_a={X-a\over w}$, for all three types (and any other type, if there are any) we have $$\begin{align}y\le 0&\implies \{Y_a\le y\}\cap\{0\le Y_a\le 1\}=\{Y_a=0\}\implies \lim_{a\to\infty}G(y,a,w)=0\\
y\ge 1&\implies \{Y_a\le y\}\cap\{0\le Y_a\le 1\}=\{0\le Y_a\le 1\}\implies \lim_{a\to\infty}G(y,a,w)=1\end{align}$$
since $\mathbb{P}(Y_a=0)=0$ due to the distribution of $X$ (hence $Y_a$) being continuous;  thus, *the types of limit differ only for $y$ in the open interval $(0,1)$*.

Here are pictures of these three types of limit:
[image: ![enter image description here]

> **Questions**:
>
> 1. How generally does this observation hold, and how can it be proved analytically? (Is this something well-known?)
> 2. What $X$ distributions (if any) do in fact yield a limit not among these three types?
> 3. In the Degenerate case, *the limit is not right-continuous* at $y=0$, so it fails to be a CDF. Nevertheless, as $a\to\infty$ the probability mass clearly concentrates in an arbitrarily small neighborhood of $y=0$ (as indicated by the plots below); so, is there a valid interpretation of this as a limiting distribution?

(My [original motivating question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2895881/16397) concerned only the asymptotic variance for just Normal vs. Lognormal. These variances of course follow from the above limiting distributions.)

---

### Examples

**Degenerate Limit**

Here are the CDFs (left) and corresponding PDFs (right) for Normal($0,1$), showing the CDFs, PDFs labeled as $G(y,a,w),\ g(y,a,w)$ for various $a$ with $w=1$:
[image]
Computations show that the limit of the distribution is degenerate at $0$ for apparently any Normal, Gumbel, Rayleigh or Maxwell distribution, or any Weibull distribution with shape parameter $> 1.$

**Uniform Limit**

Here are the CDFs (left) and corresponding PDFs (right) for LogNormal(0,1), showing the CDFs, PDFs labeled as $G(y,a,w),\ g(y,a,w)$ for various $a$ with $w=1$:
[image]
Computations show that the limit distribution is Uniform on $[0,1]$ for apparently any LogNormal, Student-t, Cauchy, Levi, Pareto, or Inverse Gamma distribution, or any Weibull distribution with shape parameter $< 1.$

**Exponential Limit**

Here are the CDFs (left) and corresponding PDFs (right) for Gamma($\alpha=2,\beta=3$), showing the CDFs, PDFs labeled as $G(y,a,w),\ g(y,a,w)$ for various $a$ with $w=1$:
[image: ![enter image description here]

Computations show that the limit distribution is Exponential on $[0,1]$ for apparently any Gamma distribution (which includes the Weibull distribution with shape parameter $= 1$), or any Logistic, Laplace, or Extreme Value distribution.

---

For reference, here's the Wolfram code I used:

```
(* Find limit(a->infinity) Pr[(X-a)/w <= y | a<=X<=a+w] for 0<y<1 *)
FindLimit[distr_,asms_]:=Module[{assms=asms~Join~{0<y<1,a>0,w>0}}, 
G[y_,a_,w_]:=Probability[(X-a)/w<=y\[Conditioned]a<=X<=a+w,X\[Distributed]distr];
Glim[y_,w_]:=Simplify[Cancel[Limit[G[y,a,w],a->Infinity]]];
Print["0<y<1: ", Assuming[assms,Glim[y,w]]];] 

(* Examples: *)

(* In[]= *)
FindLimit[ NormalDistribution[\[Mu],\[Sigma]],{\[Mu]\[Element]Reals ,\[Sigma]>0} ] 
(* Out[]= *)
0<y<1: 1

(* In[]= *)
FindLimit[ LogNormalDistribution[\[Mu],\[Sigma]],{\[Mu]\[Element]Reals ,\[Sigma]>0} ] 
(* Out[]= *)
0<y<1: y

(* In[]= *)
FindLimit[ GammaDistribution[\[Alpha],\[Beta]],{\[Alpha]>0,\[Beta]>0} ]
(* Out[]= *)
0<y<1: (E^(w/\[Beta]) (1-E^(-((w y)/\[Beta]))))/(-1+E^(w/\[Beta]))
```

Comment: As you say, the CDF of your conditional distribution is given by $G(x)=\frac{F(a+x)-F(a)}{F(a+1)-F(a)}$, where $F$ is the CDF of $X$. Since $F$ could be any right-continuous non-decreasing function going from $0$ to $1$ on $\mathbb R$, it would seem like you could get a very large class of possible functions $G$ if you allow *any* CDF $F$.

Comment: @JackM It is a large class, even though $F$ must be absolutely continuous with $F(x)<1$ for all $x$. But in this class, I haven't been able to find any examples that do *not* have one of the three stated types of limit.

Comment: Have you proven that these distributions yield only the three types of limits you mention, or have you only done numerical tests?

Comment: @JackM I do not have proof, just the Wolfram results for numerous specific distributions -- which is why I ask for "analytical proof" in my first question. (But I suppose the limit computations done by the computer algebra system are not mere "numerical tests".)

Comment: I know Gnedenko had done some work in this area on distribution tails.  Have you looked at his papers.